# INSERT INTO inside an SQL Task Editor issue

Tags: sql, ssis

Ive spent 15 minutes trying to find a post that solves my problem because it seems a pretty common one but I had no luck.

I have an SSIS package, it copies some tables from access to SQL server. It's working cool.
Now I want to work on those SQL tables.

I have a problem in the insert running inside a SQL Task Editor.

```
INSERT INTO TelepromTableNamesInfo (name, date) select ?, getdate()
```

The '?' is an input variable.

The error I get is this:

```
Error: 0xC002F210 at Insert Name, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "INSERT 
INTO TelepromTableNamesInfo 
(name, date)..." failed with the following error: "An error occurred while 
extracting the result into a 
variable of type (DBTYPE_I4)". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
"ResultSet" property not 
set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection 
not established correctly.
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to write out a ResultSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TelepromTableNamesInfo (name, date) VALUES (?, getdate())
```

Make sure your input variable is of type string.